# PhoneGap, Why an ajax post request doesnt works

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm using phonegap with jquery.

This works

```
$.ajax({url: 'samplefile.html'});
```

but this doesnt work

```
$.ajax({url: 'samplefile.html', type: 'POST'})
```

It returns a 404 error code. Why?

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
     data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
```

I think it's trying to retrieve html file thats why you are getting an error.

go through:  [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)